# How to create a generalized polygon layer from a raster?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, lidar

I have a tiff file where I have extracted vegetation in a height interval from LIDAR. At the moment the picture is kind of blurry with no data cells between vegetated cells. I would like to create a polygon layer out from this to be used as a mask on sat images with sharp boundaries. I am working with ArcMap is this possible?

I have been thinking of running a smoothing tool and then make vector, but the kernel size is to small in Arcmap, I have a resolution of about 1 meter. I would need to use the majority filer in Arcmap many times..
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> but the kernel size is to small in Arcmap

You can use the [Focal Statistic Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Focal_Statistics/009z000000qs000000/) insted of the Majority Tool. In the Focal Statistic Tool you can specify the kernel size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "simplify" parameter of the [Raster to Polygon conversion tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) to do this.

If your tiff is a floating point raster, you will need to convert it to an integer type raster before using the tool, as it only accepts integer type raster inputs.

Comment: I suspect the SIMPLIFY parameter of the Raster to Polygon Tool is not the solution. Kristian wants to eliminate some scattered pixcel. The SIMPLIFY parameter will not eleminate such pixcel. It will smoth the raster's cell edges only.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found a solution for my problem. Jens is right, maybe i was unclear with what I want to do. I tired to attached a image, but as a new user I was not allowed. Anyway I think it should be possible by doing a couple of filters with a big kernel size? My tiff is like a cloud of more or less scattered dots that I want to delineate into larger homogeneous patches/polygon. The dots represent vegetation.

I just upgraded ArcMap 9.3 to 10.0 and now after the update I cannot do raster to polygon anymore?? I still use the same original file as before when I could use it in 9.3.

Finally, my tiff file is a RGB but I am only interested in one band (all of them carry the same information) is there a way of extracting single bands in ArcMap?

best regards
Kristian